# Intellij IDEA doesn't show compile errors for Scala project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I can't see any compile errors in the project.
I've already tried to

- **to restart** IDE.
- **to enable** *Scala type-aware highlighting*(ctrl+shift+alt+e)

It didn't help.

Below is my IDE Version:

Intellij IDEA 2021.2.2(Ultimate Edition)

Comment: Maybe that was not the case here but I want to mention it. From my experience fresh installation of IntelliJ frequently has problems with loading sbt Scala projects imported from git. The workaround is to create any new sbt Scala project first and then import the project from git.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out with the following steps.

1. **Update** Scala plugin if possible.
2. **Disable** other **plugins**(e.g. Andoroid).
3. **Restart** IDE.
4. **Enable** all the needed **plugins** again.